# CSS align nested list

Tags: html, css

I have a simple nested list:

```css
ul {
 width:100px;
    list-style-position: outside;
}
ol {
 width:100px;
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

```html
<ul class="b">
  <li>Earl Grey Tea - A fine black tea</li>
  <ul class="b">
    <li>Jasmine Tea - A fabulous "all purpose" tea</li>
    <ol class="b">
      <li>English breakfast Tea - A fabulous "all purpose" tea</li>
    </ol>
  </ul>
  <li>Honeybush Tea - A super fruity delight tea</li>
</ul>
```

I want to align the nested bullets/numbers under the text of the enclosing bullets.

That is I want the *bullet* before 'Jasmine Tea' to align under the 'E' of 'Earl Grey' above, and the *number 1* of 'English breakfast' to align under the 'J' of 'Jasmine Tea'

How can this be achieved ?

(note: I am using `list-style-position: outside` to align wrapped lines correctly which I need)

Comment: Try `padding-left: 1em;` for `ul` and `ol`. Also, you don't need `list-style-position: outside`, as [`outside` is the default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position) anyway.

Comment: great, if you post an answer I'll mark it

Comment: Ah, cheers, why not. Done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The list markers live within a list's left padding. Hence, that's what you want to adjust:**

```css
ul, ol {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="b">
  <li>Earl Grey Tea - A fine black tea</li>
  <ul class="b">
    <li>Jasmine Tea - A fabulous "all purpose" tea</li>
    <ol class="b">
      <li>English breakfast Tea - A fabulous "all purpose" tea</li>
    </ol>
  </ul>
  <li>Honeybush Tea - A super fruity delight tea</li>
</ul>
```

I chose the value of `1em` as it relates to the font size, so you've got a good chance that it will put the list approximately in the desired place. Depending on the chosen font (and markers), you might want to slightly adjust this value to suit your particular situation.

Also note that you don't need `list-style-position: outside`, as [`outside` is the default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position).

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul.nudge {
 width:100px;
    list-style-position: outside;
    padding-left:20px;
}
ol.nudge {
 width:100px;
  padding-left:20px;
    list-style-position: outside;
}

ol.small-nudge {
 width:100px;
  padding-left:15px;
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

```html
<ul class="b">
  <li>Earl Grey Tea - A fine black tea</li>
  <ul class="nudge">
    <li>Jasmine Tea - A fabulous "all purpose" tea</li>
    <ol class="small-nudge">
      <li>English breakfast Tea - A fabulous "all purpose" tea</li>
    </ol>
  </ul>
  <li>Honeybush Tea - A super fruity delight tea</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to make the browser default padding-left of all child ol's and ul's consistent with the position outside spacing

```css
ul {
 width:100px;
    list-style-position: outside;
}
ol {
 width:100px;
    list-style-position: outside;
}
ul ul, ol ol, ul ol, ol ul {
    padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="b">
  <li>Earl Grey Tea - A fine black tea</li>
  <ul class="b">
    <li>Jasmine Tea - A fabulous "all purpose" tea</li>
    <ol class="b">
      <li>English breakfast Tea - A fabulous "all purpose" tea</li>
    </ol>
  </ul>
  <li>Honeybush Tea - A super fruity delight tea</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That put's the bullet of "Jasmine Tea" underneath the bullet of "Earl Grey" instead of underneath the "E", as the OP wanted.

Comment: Ah yes, misread the question. - added the 1em to get the consistent indent

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure if I understand the question but if you want the to align I would remove the `padding-left`. I would add a helper class called `padding-left-none` and then give that class `padding-left: 0px;`.

### HTML

```
<ul class="b padding-left-none">
<ol class="b padding-left-none">
```

### CSS

```
.padding-left-none {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```